# Is the camera in Kingdom Hearts 2 different from its predecessor?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-series

**Note: please try not to spoil anything, because I haven't finished KH1 yet.**

If you have played Kingdom Hearts 1 before then you should know that the camera isn't the best. It isn't terrible, but sometimes it just wont go where you want it to or it'll glitch out sometimes.

So, in Kingdom Hearts 2 is the camera changed or is it the same as Kingdom Hearts 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The camera in Kingdom Hearts 1 was one of the primary complaints by players. In KH1, the camera is controlled with <kbd>L2</kbd> and <kbd>R2</kbd> and centering the camera behind Sora was hitting both at the same time.

In KH2, they reworked the camera so the right analog stick controls the camera. This makes it much easier to control looking around, is quicker, and is much more familiar. In addition to this, clicking in the right analog stick centers the camera, and hitting <kbd>R2</kbd> toggles the camera between automatic and manual control mode. So if you get annoyed with the camera auto centering, just hit <kbd>R2</kbd>. Overall, the camera will get mostly out of your way in KH 2. At the very least, it is a vast improvement over the first games controls.

Comment: And note that the version of KH1 Final Mix that's on the upcoming HD rerelease has the camera from KH2.

Comment: These new camera controls should make the game much better. I am a person who got in to kingdom hearts years ago but never got the chance to continue the game so right now i'm waiting for my kh 2 copy ( ordered it online ) and was wondering about different things. This info helped alot thanks!